# Text not showing

Tags: html, css

```
<body>
    <div class="sts-viewport-fill">
        <nav role="navigation" class="nav navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <span class="navbar-brand">Knonet</span>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href=#>Log In</a></li>
                        <li><a href=#>Sign Up</a></li>
                        <li><a href=#>Help</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1 class="text-center">CONNECT WITH EVERYONE.<br>
                <small>Knonet aims to connect the whole world with the Internet.</small>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container sts-second-slide">
        Salut, et Bonjour!
    </div>
</body>
```

That there's my HTML. I've applied a bunch of CSS rules like so:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'Segoe UI Light', sans-serif;
  font-weight: initial;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.sts-viewport-fill {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.sts-viewport-fill .container-fluid h1 {
  margin: 250px auto 100px auto;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.navbar-collapse, nav [type="button"] {
  border: none !important;
  border-radius: 0%;
}

.sts-second-slide {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

As far as I'm concerned, this makes the `div.sts-viewport-fill` fit the entire viewport of the screen, or at least what's left of it.

The problem? See all that French there? *Salut, et Bonjour!*?
It does not appear in the browser. Observe:

[image]

Can somebody tell me what's going one here? I have a really strong feeling this has something to do with the `position: absolute;` and `top:0;bottom:0;` rules.

*Merci d'Avance!*

PS: Even if I apply a `color: #fff;` attribute to the `.sts-second-slide` selector, I still don't get a result.

Comment: Maybe its behind the first div, or its just the text color. Ty adding `.sts-second-slide { color: #ffffff; z-index: 1000; }` to bring it to the front and make it white.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `position` to that element.

Try

```
.sts-second-slide {
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
```